# Empty Request.FILES when uploading file from android client

Tags: java, android, python, django

i try upload file from android client to Django view
but on uploading that request.FILES are always empty
here is my django view code:
views.py

```
def vw_reception_uploadimage(request, phonenumber):


    if request.method == 'POST':
            print request.META
            try:
                imagePath = '/home/user/Pictures/' + str(int(time.time() * 1000)) + '.jpg'
                destination = open(imagePath, 'wb+')
                for chunk in request.FILES["uploadedfile"].chunks():
                        destination.write(chunk)
                destination.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                print request.FILES
            return HttpResponse("ok")
```

and here is my server file upload AsyncTask:
   class ServerFileUploadTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;  
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;  

    String lineEnd = "\r\n";  
    String twoHyphens = "--";  
    String boundary = "----*****";  


    private Activity activity;
    private String filepath;
    ServerFileUploadTask(Activity activity,String filepath)
    {
        this.activity=activity;
        this.filepath=filepath;
    }


    @Override  
    protected Void doInBackground(String... uri) {  

        long length = 0;  
        int progress;  
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;  
        byte[] buffer;  
        int maxBufferSize = 2048 * 1024;// 256KB  

        try {  
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(  
                    filepath));  
            File uploadFile = new File(this.filepath);  
            long totalSize = uploadFile.length(); // Get size of file, bytes  
            URL url = new URL(uri[0]);  
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  

            // Set size of every block for post  
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(2048 * 1024);// 256KB  

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs  
            connection.setDoInput(true);  
            connection.setDoOutput(true);  
            connection.setUseCaches(false);  

            // Enable POST method  
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
            if(PrefSingleton.getInstance().readPreference("token", null)!=null){
                connection.setRequestProperty("AUTHORIZATION" , "Token "+PrefSingleton.getInstance().readPreference("token", null));
                }
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");  
            connection.setRequestProperty("Charset", "UTF-8");  
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",  
                    "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);  

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(  
                    connection.getOutputStream());  


            outputStream  
                    .writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd+"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\""  
                            + this.filepath + "\"" + lineEnd);  
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);  

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();  
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);  
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];  

            // Read file  
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            while (bytesRead > 0) {  
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
                length += bufferSize;  
                progress = (int) ((length * 100) / totalSize);  
                publishProgress(progress);  

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();  
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);  
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
            }  
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);  
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens  
                    + lineEnd);  


            // Responses from the server (code and message)  
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();  
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();  

fileInputStream.close();  
            outputStream.flush();  
            outputStream.close();  

        } catch (Exception ex) {  


        }  
        return null;  
    }  



    @Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  

    }  

}
```

i tried most examples with no success and most of them use methods and class that are deprecated

i using Django version 1.7 and development server on port 8080

also using android version 4.2 
there is some other examples that use httpentity and http entity builder
that don't work for me

Answer (score 0):

i can't find solution with above code but ended up solving problem by using
Android Asynchronous Http Client library

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/